# Segment median in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, median

I have a tensor which I want to calculate the median based on segments for.
It is easy to do segment max, sum, mean and so on with tf.math.segment_max/sum/mean but how do I do it if I want segment median?

```
x = tf.constant([[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5],
                 [0.1, 0.8, 0.2, 0.6],
                 [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5],
                 [0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.9],
                 [0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.5]])

result = tf.math.segment_max(x, tf.constant([0, 1, 1, 1, 2]))

result

tf.constant([[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5],
             [0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.6],
             [0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved by converting the tensor to a ragged tensor with `tf.RaggedTensor.from_value_rowids` using `segment_ids`. Then applying `median` along each axis.

For example, to obtain ragged tensor for the above example:

```
a = tf.RaggedTensor.from_value_rowids(
    values=x,
    value_rowids=[0, 1, 1, 1, 2])
# a.shape gives (3, None, 4) - Where None has 1,3,1 dimensions
```

We then apply median to each row of the above tensor

> 1. Median of each row tensor is:

```
def median(x):
    return tfp.stats.percentile(x[None,...], 50.0, interpolation='midpoint', axis=1)
```

> 2. Segment Median

```
def segment_median(data, segment_ids):
  def median(x):
    return tfp.stats.percentile(x[None,...], 50.0, interpolation='midpoint', axis=1)

  ragged = tf.RaggedTensor.from_value_rowids(values=data, value_rowids=segment_ids)
  m = tf.map_fn(lambda x: median(x), ragged )
  return tf.squeeze(tf.stack(m))
```

> segment_median(x, tf.constant([0, 1, 1, 1, 2])) returns

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5],
       [0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.6],
       [0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.5]], dtype=float32)>
```